# OpenGL function ChangeDisplaySettings (C++) alternative

Tags: c#, c++, opengl

I am going through tutorials from NeHe and learning OpenGL, I'm using C#, but tutorials are in C++.

Is there an alternative for function `ChangeDisplaySettings` (C++ function) in C#? I need solution in lets say "pure" OpenGL, i.e. without library CsGL, because I have to use another library where isn't classes like OpenGLControl.

Comment: It's an old article, but it sounds relevant: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms812499.aspx

Comment: Which values that change in ChangeDisplaySettings are you concerned with? If it's mainly things like width and height, then you can get the same effect by setting the glViewport(), and either glOrtho(), or glFrustum ().

Answer (score 4):

`ChangeDisplaySettings` is *not* an OpenGL function. It is a *Windows* function. It's part of the Win32 API. So you can just call the C# equivalent, or if there isn't one, just use PInvoke to call the C function.

Answer (score 0):

OpenGL itself is only a rendering api. You have to bind it with your system.
Those bindings vary from system to system. In Windows it is called WGL, but most of the work is done by WinApi.

Look for some materials/tutorials about C# and OpenGL and there should be something for you.